# eachFile in Gradle Copy-task is not working

Tags: gradle, groovy

I have a Gradle rule like:

```
tasks.addRule("Pattern: updatelight<Path> (copies files to ../<Path>).") { String taskName ->
  if (taskName.startsWith("updatelight")) {
    task([ "type": Copy ], taskName) {
      
      
      def projectGroups = (sub + root)
      
      def testEnvPath = taskName - 'updatelight'
      into ("../${testEnvPath}/")
      
      
      logger.info("Copies user.xml")
      projectGroups.each { project ->
        if (!project.isEmpty()) {
          from (project.output) {
            into "cfg/${project.newPath}"
            
            eachFile { file ->
              println "  ${file.sourcePath} -> ${file.path}" 
              println '----------------------------------------------'
            }
          }
        }
      }
[...]
```

My problem is, eachFile { ... } is not printing to console. Any hint? I am a Gradle-newbie and just try to add some logging to the existing task.

Comment: It might not fix your problem. But you have declared a closure variable called "project". Don't do this, it's overriding/hiding the core "project" property (eg [Project.getProject()](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#getProject--))

Comment: Thanks for the hint, although it does not solve the problem as you guessed it.

Comment: Sorry, the code should work. As I said, I am learning Gradle. Because of cache there were no actions/logging to console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no problem with the code. Because of cache there were to actions taken therefore no logging.